# How to merge/copy a single column's values in one sheet into another sheet based on the values of a column using excel?

Tags: excel, vba

I have two excel spreadsheets (that I can put onto two separate sheets within one sheet, one call A, and one called B).

Spreadsheet A/Or Sheet A

```
NAME,SPORT
Jordan,Tennis
Jordan,Basketball
Jess,Tennis
Mike,Baseball
```

Spreadsheet B/Or Sheet B

```
NAME,AGE
Jorden,5
Jess, 6
Mike, 10
```

I want to make it so that I can merge the two spreadsheets such that the "Age" column is added to Sheet A with the resulting spreadsheet:

```
NAME,SPORT,AGE
Jordan,Tennis,5
Jordan,Basketball,5
Jess,Tennis,6
Mike,Baseball,10
```

How can I do this?

Assume there is an exact match for names in Spreadsheet B to Spreadsheet A (first names only, no need to worry about last names).

Range of values could be variable, but if it's just a matter of making sure the range is updated as new values are put in manually, it's okay. Unless there is a smarter way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In sheet A, cell C2 :

`=INDEX('Sheet B'!$B$2:$B$4,MATCH('Sheet A'!A2,'Sheet B'!$A$2:$A$4,0))`

Things to consider :

- Is the size of your data variable ? > Do you need to adapt the look up range ?
- Will you have duplicates in the names ? > What if two different kids are called "Jordan"